# Super key swapped with alt key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

My super key swapped randomly with the alt key.
For example, when I click super key nothing happens, but when I click alt, the shortcuts help pops up.To close a window I need to click super+f4. In keyboard settings, everything is configured correctly.

I've tried to add `setxbkmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win` to startup, and it works until i change windows with alt+tab. Can anyone help? It is very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_lalt_lwin
```

See the difference? lalt = left alt, ralt = right alt. The same with lwin and rwin.

To restore default

```
setxkbmap -option
```

Comment: It solved my problem but I still wonder why the keys swapped. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I do not know. I never experienced such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-mode keyboard, there's a button to swap from Win to Mac layouts (Win/Mac).

- In Win's, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is to the *left* of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- In Mac's, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>) key  is to *left* of the <kbd>Super</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>).

These keys are swapped in the design of actual keyboards, so probably you've changed this configuration by accident.

---

**Solution**: Look up how to change from one layout to another in the manual of your multi-mode keyboard.

In my case, I was using a RAPOO 8050T and  reverted back to <kbd>Win</kbd>'s by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>. Now <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are mapped to the correct keys.